# React does not show the image when is uploaded

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react and what I need is that when an image is loaded it shows a preview.

I have the next code:

```
const [logoSrc, setLogoSrc] = React.useState("");

const handleChangeLogo = (event) => {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    setLogoSrc(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
  }
};

<Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
  <label htmlFor="image">
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      className={classes.input}
      id="logo"
      type="file"
      onChange={handleChangeLogo}
    />
    <label htmlFor="logo">
      <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
        <PhotoCamera />
      </IconButton>
    </label>
    {logoSrc ?? <img src={logoSrc} alt="uploaded-logo" />}
  </label>
</Grid>;
```

this code show me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator (or the wrong initial state).

You've set `logoSrc` to an empty string so the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) is not what you want.

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

`logoSrc` is not null, or undefined (as you set the initial state to be an empty string) so `??` will always return the left hand operand, which is `logoSrc` - a string. This is why first, you see nothing (an empty string being rendered) and subsequently you see the URL.

The solution is to either a:

1. Use null or undefined as the initial state:

```
const [logoSrc, setLogoSrc] = React.useState(null);
```

OR

2. Do a different check:

```
{logoSrc == '' ? null : <img src={logoSrc} alt="uploaded-logo" />}
```

Comment: You right, I did not realize, thank you very match